# Particle selection

Tags: grammar

I’m learning a Japanese and one of tasks was to pick a particle to the following question:

> 彼女___泣かれて 、 私は困ってしまった

The translation given in the app is “She cried and I worried”. The app says the particle to be used is に, however I completely don’t understand that, since with a given translation “she” is not an agent of action. Can you please advise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what's known as the 'suffering passive'. An example of the basic structure is 「私はいじめっこにリュックを盗まれた」, with the agent marked by に and the passive construction, but the patient of the verb remains marked by を unlike in a standard passive. It indicates that the subject was caused trouble by the action.

Though I don't know what you mean by 'since with a given translation “she” is not an agent of action.' In the given translation, 'she' is the agent of 'cried'.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the agent - I think I confused it with causative, and assumed that agent is someone who made her cry.